# colspan in Dash Python

Tags: python, html-table, plotly-dash

I want to make an HTML table in Dash(Python). How can I apply colspan=2 in Dash?

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Business</th>
      <th>NetWorth</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>cde</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">You</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply pass relevant keyword arguments to the corresponding Dash object,

```
from dash import html

html.Th(colSpan=2)
```